# Get launcher's icon resource identifier

Tags: android, android-resources, android-package-managers

Here is how I'm getting the launcher icon for an app (Koltin code but this question is nothing related to Kotlin):

```
val packageManager = packageManager()
val applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0)
val drawable = applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager)
```

My point now that `TaskManager` deprecated the use of non-res icons, is to get the value or the `DrawableRes` of that launcher icon (an identifier that would equals `R.drawable.ic_launcher` for example).

I couldn't find a way. Is this possible dynamically (or is it impossible due to `R.java` generation?), without explicitely typing it?

Comment: where do you want to get an icon from? Where is the icon located in your project?

Comment: Input is a package name. It's for a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the corresponding resource id of the icon and you know the package name and the item name, you can do it like that:

```
int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("nameOfResource", "drawable", this.getPackageName());
```

"*this*" is the activity where the code runs on.

"*nameOfResource*" is the name of the icon itself (without file extension)
"*drawable*" is the name of the **res** subfolder, where the icon lies.

You can find the function documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Alternatively you can receive the resource id of an application is this one:

```
final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
final ApplicationInfo applicationInfo=packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName,PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
final int appIconResId=applicationInfo.icon;
```

It is similar to your approach.
Your search for all *resources* of your application and get access the icon id as a member of the information returned.

Comment: That's more like it. However I would like the launcher icon, the one registered in the manifest, and not having to _guess_ it's `nameOfResource`. Otherwise, seems like the best we could achieve.

Comment: @shkschneider could you tell me, what to you want to do with this resource id of the icon? Maybe you don't even need it for your goal.

Comment: I simply whant a library to expose a `BaseActivity` that calls `setTaskDescription()` by itself. I used `ApplicationInfo.loadIcon()` before but now that it's deprecated I wanted to update my code. Not sure it's possible ^^

Comment: Ok i can see your point. I have editted my answer with an alternative approach similar to yours. The reason why this is deprecated is, that the ApplicationIcon should always be static --> constant. Why do you want to set in in TaskDescription, if it is already defined in manifest file, You could also simply use the setTaskDescription() without the need of an icon. A bit more source code could help me to understand your intentions.

Comment: Yes, that was what I wanted. Not sure why I missed that but thanks for `ApplicationInfo.icon`.